# Laravel - Subdomain localization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I want to set the localization using subdomains. I've managed to set up subdomain wildcards and it's working fine. However I'd like to set up filters.
For example I was thinking of setting up an array of available countries in the config:

```
<?php

return array(

    'available' => array(
        'uk',
        'fr',
        'de'
    )

);
```

Then in my routes I need a way of filtering a group. For the moment my code is the following without any filters:

```
<?php

$homeController = 'MembersController@profile';

if ( ! Sentry::check())
{
    $homeController = 'HomeController@index';
}

Route::group(['domain' => '{locale}.'.Config::get('app.base_address')], function() use ($homeController)
{
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => $homeController]);

    Route::post('users/register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'UsersController@register']);
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas for filtering the group?

Also if the subdomain isn't valid how can I redirect to something like uk.domainname.com?

Thank you in advance for any help, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could solve this in your routes with a filter, that will be executed first. it checks then for the available subdomains and if it doesn't find it, it redirects to a default subdomain.

```
Route::filter('subdomain', function()
{
    $subdomain = current(explode('.', Request::url()));
    if (!in_array($subdomain, Config::get('app.countries.available'))) {
        return Redirect::to(Config::get('app.default_subdomain') . '.' . Config::get('app.base_address'));
    }
});

Route::group(['before' => 'subdomain'], function()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It should be `if(!in_array($subdomain, Config:.get('app.countries.available')))`

Comment: isn't there an error in the fix?   Config:.get('app   should be Config::get('app

Answer (score 1):

In your `app/filters.php` I would write something like this. You will have a to create a new variable in your config called `availableSubdomains` with your subdomains array.

```
<?php
Route::filter('check_subdomain', function()
{
    $subdomain = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('subdomain');
    if (!in_array($subdomain, Config::get('app.availableSubdomains')))
        return Redirect::home();
});
```

Then I will add a before filter in your group route in `app/routes.php`

```
<?php
Route::group(
    ['domain' => '{locale}.'.Config::get('app.base_address'),
    'before' => 'check_subdomain']
, function() use ($homeController)
{
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => $homeController]);

    Route::post('users/register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'UsersController@register']);
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
});
```

Sorry, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Great answer thanks. Really clear syntax aswell. One thing though, ->getParemeter('subdomain') should be ->getParameter('locale')

Comment: @xonorageous Really, we should use `->getParemeter('locale')`? I thought locale was referring to the language used for translation. But if you set your locale regarding subdomain it should be good. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

For subdomains where the language designator is the first part of the subdomain name, like:  en.domain.com/section  here is what I've used for laravel 5.1

this uses getHost which avoids the problem with http/https showing up first

> app\Http\routes.php:
>
> ```
> Route::filter('subdomain', function() {
>   $locale_url = current(explode('.', Request::getHost()));
>   if (!in_array($locale_url, Config::get('app.countries_available'))) {
>   return Redirect::to(Config::get('app.default_subdomain') . '.' . Config::get('app.base_address'));
>   }
>   App::setLocale($locale_url);
> });
> ```

it is necessary to add things like:

> ```
>  config/app.php:  
>      'countries_available' => ['en','es'],
> ```

to find the variable

finally, to add it to a route

> app\Http\routes.php:
>
> ```
> Route::group(['before' => 'subdomain'], function()
> {
>   Route::get('/', 'control@func');  
>   ...
> });
> ```

Comment: looks like filters are actually depreciated  so this needs to be re-written as middleware.  the nice part of the filter was that it seemed practice to include it in the routes.php file, rather than in another location.